# Skype4py set video chat dialog to fullscreen

Tags: python, dialog, skype, skype4py

I'm trying to get the video chat window automatically in fullscreen when it appears. 
Using Skype 2.2 und Skype4py under Linux.

Can not find a way to maximize the video dialog with Skype4py.

Ideas? Thanks a lot.